# Delete rows that the condicion gives true or false in a DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe that i extract from an excel using a sql selection:

```
sql_con_obj = SqlConnector()
sql_con_obj.connect()
cursor = sql_con_obj.con.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
df = pandas.read_sql_query(sql, sql_con_obj.con)
df.to_excel("incidencias.xlsx")
```

I have a column named "Number":

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 125 entries, 0 to 124
Data columns (total 22 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------               --------------  -----
 0   Number               125 non-null    object
```

I will give an example of how that column looks like :

```
print(df['Number'])
0      S210401
1      S210401
2      S210401
3      S210401
4      S210401
            ...
121    I210224
122    I210223
123    I210219
124    I210211
125    I210118
```

I then filter the ones that start with letter "S":

```
S = ['S']
cond=df['Number'].str.startswith(tuple(S))
0       True
1       True
2       True
3       True
4       True
       ...
121    False
122    False
123    False
124    False
125    False
```

What i want now is to remove the ones that are True and stay with the "I"'s so i though of doing this :

```
df = df.drop(df[cond].index)
```

The outcome when i print

```
print(df['Number']
120    I210224
121    I210223
122    I210219
123    I210211
124    I210118
125    I210118
```

But the problem is that in the excel the rows dont get removed ... What can i do to solve this ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel at all?

Comment: Im pulling that information that is an excel, maybe i need to specifie that in the begging.

Comment: Transforming a dataframe doesn't change the source file at all.

Comment: Ok im dumb but i will keep this question just in case someone has the same problem. I used a similar condicion in my code  where i change the dataframe before but in that case it changed because i then use pandas.ExcelWriter and format the length of the columns.... sorry and thank you because of you i found the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
S = ['S']
cond=df['Number'].str.startswith(tuple(S))
```

After the above code Just use `~`(bitwise negation operator) pass the boolean mask(cond) to your dataframe:

```
df=df[~cond]
```

Finally:

```
df.to_excel("incidencias.xlsx")
```

Comment: Yup that's it !